# How do I establish a one-to-one relationship using Database First?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When my models were generated, many relationships were mapped automagically. However, some of the relationships are "incorrect" (or at least, not what I want), or missing.

I don't doubt that this is because of poor database design, but based on my role in this project there is not much I can do to fix that. However, is there something I can do in my application code to fix the mapping?

Here is one example:

I would like to map the StoreProductId property to the StoreProducts table.

[image: tables]

### ProductAttributePriceAdjustment

```
public partial class ProductAttributePriceAdjustment
{
        public int AdjustmentId { get; set; }
        public int StoreProductId { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProductSizeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Adjustment { get; set; }
        public int PointsAdjustment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProductColorID { get; set; }

        public StoreProduct StoreProduct { get; set; }
}
```

### StoreProduct

```
public partial class StoreProduct
{
    public int StoreProductID { get; set; }
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public bool Featured { get; set; }
    public bool Clearance { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, when I try calling something like:

```
@adjustment.StoreProduct.ProductID
```

I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

---

### Update 1

I followed Frans' advice and updated my model to this:

```
public partial class ProductAttributePriceAdjustment
{
    public int AdjustmentId { get; set; }
    public int StoreProductId { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductSizeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Adjustment { get; set; }
    public int PointsAdjustment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductColorID { get; set; }

    public virtual StoreProduct StoreProduct { get; set; }
}
```

but am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a 1:1 mapping in entity framework like this.  It's not supported.

Entity Framework only supports 1:1 mappings in which both tables have a shared primary key (ie they have the same primary key, and one of them is a foreign key to the other).  In your situation, you are actually creating a 1 to many, because there is no guarantee that StoreProductId is unique.